# Python: inquirer validate function

Tags: python, function, validation, lambda, inquirer

Can I use a separate function for inquirer validate function or it has to be lambda function?

I'm trying to ask a question about shift count. So I have to check it's number or not.

I wrote a function that checks its argument number or not and returns a boolean value.

```
import inquirer
import string

def shiftCount(count):
    for i in count:
        if i in string.digits:
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True

question = [
    inquirer.Text('count', message='Enter a number',validate=???)
]

answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)
```

I know that validate function must take two arguments. But I couldn't manage to write it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda or a user defined function. You can find some implementations [here](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-inquirer/latest/python-inquirer.pdf).

```
def count_validation(answers, current):
    pass #write your validation logic here. current variable hold the input value
```

and then call

```
question = [
    inquirer.Text('count', message='Enter a number',validate=count_validation)
]
```